# Relation to User class via pointer: Error code 102

Tags: pointers, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have 2 classes: `User`, `Books`

In `User` table I have: `objectId`, `AuthorName`

In `Books` table I have: `objectId`, `BookName`, `authorIDptr`

`AuthorIDptr` is a Pointer to `User` class

When I run this query:

```
var bookQuery = PFQuery(className:"Books")
bookQuery.whereKey("authorIDptr", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
bookQuery.includeKey("authorIDptr")

var userQuery = PFUser.query()
userQuery.whereKey("BookName", matchesKey: "Curious George", inQuery: bookQuery)

userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {....
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Error Domain=Parse Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 102.)" UserInfo=0x7ff2e26f4660 {error=pointer field authorIDptr needs a pointer value, code=102} {
>       code = 102;
>       error = "pointer field authorIDptr needs a pointer value";
>   }

The Class is populated with data.  When i click on the pointer in the `Books` class, it loads the appropriate `User` class record.

Can someone help show me what I am doing wrong.

What I want to happen: I want all `AuthorName`s of a book to show up in a tableview.

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
bookQuery.whereKey("authorIDptr", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
```

into this:

```
bookQuery.whereKey("authorIDptr", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
```

Pointers in parse are available via `object` and not `objectId`. So when you need to query with pointer, you just pass the whole object to the query and the parse will do the rest for you.

Comment: Actually, I got it...just update the key with the object...not the objectID...thanks again!